# Custom Lift tags don't work

Tags: eclipse, scala, openid, lift, sbt

The following types of tags in Lift do not seem to work for me:

```
<lift:snippet type="MyClass:render" />
<lift:MyClass.render/>
<lift:MyClass/>
```

Using these tags results in a Class Not Found error. If I attempt to call a class using

```
<div class=lift:myclass.mymethod />
```

it can work. Or if I call it using span tags. For instance, the Hello World example in Pollak's *Simply Lift* works for me, successfully displaying the Howdy method with the following code:

```
<span class="lift:helloWorld.howdy">
      Welcome to your Lift app at <span id="time">Time goes here</span>
</span>
```

Currently, my problem is coming from attempting to implement *Exploring Lift*'s (aka *The Lift Book*) OpenID example in Chapter 13.1. I have downloaded OpenID4Java using sbt as well as the lift-openid library. That example can be found at http://exploring.liftweb.net/master/index-13.html. I have implemented the change to the Boot class, and created the OpenID class and the SimpleOpenIDVendor class. But creating an html file containing

```
 <lift:OpenID.form>
  <openId:renderForm/>
 </lift:OpenID.form>
```

causes the following error to be displayed in the browser:

```
Error processing snippet: openid.form
Reason: Class Not Found
XML causing this error:
<lift:openid.form xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<openid:renderform>
</openid:renderform></lift:openid.form>
```

The class OpenID was placed in a package that starts with the package code, which is being implicitly found by Lift. It is included in the Boot.scala file with the line

```
LiftRules.addToPackages("code")
```

So, I am at a loss. Any ideas?

Note that other lift tags such as lift:bind-at and lift:surround and the like work fine.

Comment: You problem is likely the way the new(er) HTML5 parser works.  You should try using `lift:open_id` as the tag.

Comment: That looks like its it, as I just found Pollak's post about it: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liftweb/H-xe1uRLW1c

Comment: and see [this](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/3948df1eee6ec271/) thread for the latest way to invoke s snippet when using html5 templates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As dave posted under my original comment, the problem was the HTML5 parser. Lift is case-sensitive, and cannot find a class with varying case. Since the HTML5 parser automatically makes tags lowercase, you can't use custom lift tags anymore. Instead, you have to use something like

```
<div class="Lift:MyClass.render"></div>
```

Note that you **CANNOT** have

```
<div class="Lift:MyClass.render" />
```

as HTML5 apparently does not support such tags.

My OpenID4Java problem is therefore resolved by using:

```
<div class="lift:OpenID.renderForm">         
</div>
```

Why I don't need to use openid.form still is uncertain. It could be possible I'm implementing it slightly off, but I confirmed that it will take me to an openid login page if I put in the openid link, so it is indeed functional.

Sources:

- http://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/liftweb/H-xe1uRLW1c
- https://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/3948df1eee6ec271/ (thanks fmpwizard)